# How to convert Array string to an Array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, string

This is my string format

```
[["1258765200","12350"],["1259370000","13000"],["1259974800","11840"]]
```

and i want array like

```
array(
[0] => array([0] => 1258765200, [1] => 12350)
.... 
and so on....
)
```

I don't have any idea how i can achieve this, Please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this: `json_decode($string, true)`

Answer (score 4):

Convert your string into a PHP multi dimensional array using `json_decode($str, TRUE)`.